# Argument of type {...} is not assignable to parameter of type [ ]

Tags: database, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventDetail } from '../../models/event-detail/event-detail.interface';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-event',
  templateUrl: 'event.html',
})
export class EventPage {

  eventDetail = {} as EventDetail;

  eventDetailRef$: AngularFireList<EventDetail[]>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.eventDetailRef$ = this.database.list('event-detail');
  }

  addEvent( eventDetail: EventDetail) {

    this.eventDetailRef$.push({
      eventName: this.eventDetail.eventName,
      eventDesc: this.eventDetail.eventDesc,
    });

  }

}
```

i followed a tutorial way back a year ago, i've rad "Upgrading to Angularfire 5.0", googled the same problem, result are quite different

the error message are:

"Argument of type '{ eventName: string; eventDesc: String; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventDetail[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'eventName' does not exist in type 'EventDetail[]'."

and my EventDetail Interface:

```
export interface EventDetail {
    eventName: string;
    eventDesc: String;
    lat: number;
    lgt: number;

}
```

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlYFY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `eventDetailRef$: AngularFireList<EventDetail[]>;` to `eventDetailRef$: AngularFireList<EventDetail>`

Because because your type is `Array<Array>` and you trying to push a single item

Comment: thank you this solve the error, now i need to retrieve user current location and push it along side the name and description, thank you very much!

Comment: @HaHadi  you are welcome, please upvote if the answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

The error message specifies that you are trying to assign `{ eventName: string; eventDesc: String; }` to an **array** of `EventDetail`

The `push` method is expecting an array, not a single instance.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, i am fairly new in ionic.