# Argument of type {} is not assignable to parameter of type []

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I working in angular 2 at the moment, I get error after mapping data from backend, and try to call function. Error text below

**Argument of type '{ date: Date; recipes: Recipe[]; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Day[]'.**

The Day model looks like this:

```
import { Recipe } from "../recipes/recipe.model";

export class Day {
public date: Date;
public recipes :Recipe[]

constructor(date: Date, recipes ?: Recipe[]) {
    this.date = date;
    this.recipes = recipes;
  }

getDate(){
    return this.date;
  }
}
```

Error occurred in setDays method, the passed parameter is invalid.

```
loadDays() {
    return this.http.get<Day[]>(
        this.urlDays,
    ).pipe(
        map((days => {
            return days.map(day => {
                return {
                    ...day,
                    recipes: day.recipes ? day.recipes : []
                };

            });
        })),
        tap(days => {
            this.daysService.setDays(days);
        }),
    );
}
```

In this part of code:

```
return {
                    ...day,
                    recipes: day.recipes ? day.recipes : []
                };
```

I check if data i get have recipes if they have i don't chenge recipe, and if i don't have  recipe i  add empty array of type Recipe.

DaysService code :

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

import { Day } from "./day.model";

@Injectable()
export class DaysService {

  private startDate: Date = new Date(new Date().getTime());
  private dayLongInMS: number = 86400000;
  private daysShown: Array<Day> = [];
  daysChanged = new Subject<Day[]>();

  getDays() {
        return this.daysShown.slice();
  }

  setDays(days: Day[]) {
        this.daysShown = days;
        this.daysChanged.next(this.daysShown.slice());
    }
```

I think i need some method to grouped back this 2 parameters after divided it be operator triple dot **(date: Date; recipes: Recipe[];)** to one **(Day[])** property.

I find similar problem here:
[Argument of type {...} is not assignable to parameter of type [ ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228168/argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type)
 But I don't know how to use it me case. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: What's the signature of the `this.daysService.setDays` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning instances of the `Day` class. The http client doesn't create `Day` instances just because they're given as the generic type. And the compiler is complaining because you are creating objects that don't conform to the interface of the `Day` class.

Instead, you will need to create `Day` instances in the `map` operator.

```js
loadDays() {
  return this.http.get(this.urlDays).pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      return response.map(day => new Day(day.date, day.recipes || []));
    }),
    tap(days => {
      this.daysService.setDays(days);
    }),
  );
}
```

If you want to ensure that `Day` instances are always initialised with a non-null `recipes`, you should handle that in your constructor rather than relying on the calling code.

```js
export class Day {
  public date: Date;
  public recipes :Recipe[]

  constructor(date: Date, recipes ?: Recipe[]) {
    this.date = date;
    this.recipes = recipes || [];
  }

  getDate(){
    return this.date;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kurt Hamilton for answer, i thinking about this solution but, i looking for some solution using only the pipe to transform data to corect form without using constructor in map method.

Comment: You need to conform to the interface of the `Day` class. You either need to use the constructor or return an object with all of the properties and functions. You don't really want to recreate the function logic, so I would say the constructor approach is the best way.

Comment: You could always make the `getDate()` function optional on the `Day` class, but then what's the point of having it if it's optional...

Comment: Through experience I have found that it's generally better to retain manual control over the communication of data between different layers. A little bit of extra typing now might seem like a pain, but it is generally beneficial in the long run.